# Couldn't find a package.json file when setting up Github actions for Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, github-actions, firebase-hosting

When initializing github actions for firebase hosting i specified the following:

Set up the workflow to run a build script before every deploy? Yes
What script should be run before every deploy? yarn run build.

This workflow gives me the error

```
Run yarn run build
yarn run v1.22.10
error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/home/runner/work/SpaceBar/SpaceBar"
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I have a package.json file in my project directory. Why is it saying that it cannot find it?

firebase-hosting-merge.yml is in the directory called spacebar, which contains another directory called spacebar containing the package.json file.
Is there anyway to cd into the sub directory in this file

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: yarn run build
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the `actions/checkout` action gave you access to the repository files and directories, you can just `cd` into the directory where the `package.json` file is located before executing the `yarn` command. Otherwise, it will only look for it at the repository root.

Example (for your second step)

```
run: |
   cd spacebar/spacebar
   yarn run build
```

Comment: I have the same issue and this did not work for me. It just says that it can't find the directory 'spacebar/spacebar'.

Comment: Can you share the repository to check what can be wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot as its company property...

Comment: @malthe.w you'd have to replace it with your own directory...

Comment: @AlexandreMoreira I recommend reading my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error with a similar setup. Unfortunately though, the answer marked as accepted did not solve my problem.

However, after lots and lots of googling, I did manage to solve my problem and just wanna share what I found in case anybody else is still having issues like I had:

As *GuiFalourd* correctly mentioned, the error is asking you to be in the directory where your package.json file is located. But as it turns out, there are multiple ways of doing this - some more correct than others. In my specific case, the action I'm using and all of the commands running in it are meant to be run in a specific directory and so I chose to declare the directory with the keyword `working-directory` in the `defaults` setting:

```yaml
name: Build & deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./frontend
    
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x]
steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        
    - name: Clean Cache
      run: |
        npm cache clean --force
    - name: CI Install
      run: |
        npm ci
    - name: NPM Install
      run: |
        npm install      
    - name: Production Build
      run: |
        npm run build
      env:
        CI: false
    - name: Unit Tests
      run: |
        npm run test --passWithNoTests
```

The other working alternative would have been to set the `working-directory` in every step with a command. This can be useful if you want to run a specific command in a specific directory once, while everything else is run somewhere else. Downside is it looks messy and is redundant if everything is meant to be run in the same directory anyway:

```yaml
name: Build & deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x]
        
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        
    - name: Clean Cache
      working-directory: ./frontend
      run: |
        npm cache clean --force
    - name: CI Install
      working-directory: ./frontend
      run: |
        npm ci
    - name: NPM Install
      working-directory: ./frontend
      run: |
        npm install      
    - name: Production Build
      working-directory: ./frontend
      run: |
        npm run build
      env:
        CI: false
    - name: Unit Tests
      working-directory: ./frontend
      run: |
        npm run test --passWithNoTests
```

**DO NOTE:** The `working-directory` keyword does not work for the `uses` and `with` keywords. Depending on what deploy action you're using, you will have to set this in  its own `env` settings.

In my case, my final YML file looks like this:

```yaml
name: Build & deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./frontend
    
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x]
        
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        
    - name: Clean Cache
      run: |
        npm cache clean --force
    - name: CI Install
      run: |
        npm ci
    - name: NPM Install
      run: |
        npm install      
    - name: Production Build
      run: |
        npm run build
      env:
        CI: false
    - name: Unit Tests
      run: |
         npm run test --passWithNoTests
    - name: Deploy to S3
      uses: jakejarvis/s3-sync-action@master
      with:
        args: --acl public-read --delete
      env:
        AWS_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.AWS_PRODUCTION_BUCKET_NAME }}
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        AWS_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
        SOURCE_DIR: "./frontend/build"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please only edit my answer if it is relevant to the question at hand. Irrelevant edits will be rolled back.

Comment: Confirm this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using *working-directory* worked for me

```
- name: NPM install, dependencies, build, and test
  working-directory: ./WebApp
  run: |
    npm install
    npm run build --if-present
```